# What Regex expression for fscanf() will ignore any character/string/special character in a line?

Tags: c, regex, scanf

I am trying to come up with a regex expression that can ignore any character in a line (after I read my relevant input).  In a way, its treating the characters after a certain point in the txt file as a comment, but the comment is 'anything' but the relevant information I need.  Here's what I have and its worked, but am wondering if there's a more elegant way to handle this:

`fscanf(input_file, "%*[a-zA-Z .^$*+?()[{\'\" \t]", temp_char)`

`temp_char` is a char* buffer.

Thanks

Comment: `fscanf()` won't recognize regular expression.

Comment: @MikeCAT: true, `fscanf` accepts character classes, that some people erroneously call regular expressions.

Comment: @chqrlie I am still confused by the stated `and its worked`. The posted format string has `space` occuring twice, and misses some characters e.g. `]}`. Hard to tell whether those are typos, or the question being (meant to be) asked is maybe different than the one as written.

Comment: @MikeCAT: the character class is indeed incomplete, it is possible that it does consume the extra characters in the OP's lines because all of them are enumerated in the character class. Inelegant and unreliable. Much better to use my simple proposal.

Comment: @chqrlie - when i say 'its worked', I mean that its worked for the cases that I've presented to the code. I left out the closed brackets from the proposed idea `]}` but I didn't present closed brackets in my tested inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to consume every character different from `\n` and the final `\n`, use these statements:

```
fscanf(input_file, "%*[^\n]");
fscanf(input_file, "%*c");
```

The first ignores all characters different from `\n`, but fails if there are none.
The second consumes the `\n` character.